# Android studio 2.1 emulator control disabled

Tags: android, emulation

When I start the divece using emulator I can't use Emulator control because it is disabled and when I use the real divece I have the same problem. How to make it work?    [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcQ2a.png)

Answer (score 0):

it is for versions above 2.0...

[image: enter image description here 123]